# 'tooltip' is not working in python leaflet mapping

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I am using python 3.6 Following is my simple code:

```
import folium
city_location = [-23.6573395, -46.5322504]

m = folium.Map(location=city_location, zoom_start=15, tiles='openstreetmap')

folium.Marker(city_location, popup='<i>Teste</i>', tooltip='Click me!').add_to(m)
m
```

But I keep getting the error saying:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tooltip'
```

What can I do to show a tooltip upon my marker ?

Comment: Your code is correct. Which version of folium are you using ?

Comment: I am not sure how to check the version but I installed it 2.5 years ago. Should I update it?

Comment: of course you should ! Library like this one constantly update. Btw you can check your version by performing `pip freeze > requirements.txt` then check the pip requirements.txt file, it should be a version number there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tooltip was added with the version [v.0.0.6](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/releases/tag/v0.6.0).
Refer to this issue : https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/pull/724

From your comment, it was six month after you installed it.
So, update your dependencies and it should work

You can check your version by doing `pip freeze > requirements.txt`

Check the folium version there. If it is under 0.0.6, then perform a :
`pip install folium --upgrade` and you are done

Also, check the [Release page](https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/releases), this library is in active development, so you should always update if you want to enjoy and test the last features !

Comment: Thanks my savior. Folium version was 0.5.0